# how to check if username exists in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

All the username and password details are present in oracle DB. I am using servlets and jsp as backend. When user name is registered through a java servlet, it sits in oracle db.

Now I want to check if existing username is already available. I know its like making ajax call to fetch the info but what do I pass as URL? Shall I pass a url pattern of a servlet (example: `url:'./getRecords'`) ? or is there any other way of doing it?

Also using back end as servlet and jsp a good idea? I wonder why people use node js and mondo DB with angular js.

Comment: create an endpoint on your backend such that your ajax can reach it. And the method defined at your endpoint should return the sql result.

Comment: What endpoint? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HojHE3ndnZeugGzZugWs?p=preview) :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem get solved with this:
I am using **php MVC framework** with **angularjs**.

I have written **Directive** for **validating unique field** (checking from DB).
This is the script:
**app.js**

```
var base_url="http://localhost/mysystem/";   
 var angularapp = angular.module('angularapp', ['ngRoute','angularControllers','uniqueField']);  
    angularapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/add_user', {
                controller : 'AddUserCtrl',
                templateUrl : base_url+'angular/partials/add_user.php'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/dashboard'
            });
    }]);

    //unique field   --creating directive
    angular.module('uniqueField', [])
    .directive('uniqueField', function($http) {
      var toId;
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) { 
          //when the scope changes, check the field.
          scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(value) {
            // if there was a previous attempt, stop it.
            if(toId) clearTimeout(toId);

            // start a new attempt with a delay to keep it from
            toId = setTimeout(function(){
              // call to some API that echo "1" or echo "0"
              $http.get(base_url+'controller/check_unique?check=' + value).success(function(data) {

                //set the validity of the field
                if (data == "1") 
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueField', false);
                }
                else if (data == "0")
                {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueField', true);
                }
              });
            }, 200);
          })
        }
      }
    });
```

This is the HTML:

```
User Name: <input required type="text"  ng-model="uname" name="uname" id="uname" unique-field  /><br/>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="form_add.uname.$dirty && form_add.uname.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="form_add.uname.$error.required">User Name is required.</span>    
        <span ng-show="form_add.uname.$error.uniqueField">User Name already exists.</span>
    </span>
```

**Note:** submit button gets **disabled** if the *username is already exists*.
Hope this might help.

Answer (score -1):

The back end and the front end are totally separate. Most AngularJS calls are just standard HTTP requests, using `$http`. It doesn't matter what server side language or DB the server is using, that is essentially a black box as far as front end implementation goes.

You need a web interface on your server that can be queried to check if a username already exists or not. Then simply call that URL using `$http` with the desired username as a parameter from AngularJS. Your server side code will then run a query to decide if the username is unique or not and then return a payload stating whether or not it is available.